# Optimize the selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can we optimize this selector:

```
$(".testClass div#testID:eq(0)")
```

Comment: How can you call eq on an id? There's only one of them?

Comment: To put some context on the answers your getting, `id` attributes should be unique, therefore using an `id` selector - `#testID` - should only ever return you one element, therefore everything else in your selector is redundant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Not if the code is used on multiple pages but should only apply to one, when both pages contain an element with the same ID.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Good point. I suppose in that case only the `:eq()` is redundant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Yeah the `:eq()` is definitely redundant no matter what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As only one element can have a given ID, simply do

```
$("#testID")
```

Comment: This *could* be too optimised... if the code is included on multiple pages, but should only apply to one when more than one page has an element with this ID, then it can be useful to qualify the ID selector.

Comment: @JamesAllardice yes but in that case we haven't the needed information to optimize.

Answer (score 2):

The very optimised version:

```
$("#testID")
```

Comment: Too slow - beaten to it by @destroy!

Comment: @BillyMoon by 2 seconds as well. Harsh ;)

Comment: @BillyMoon Just `$("#testID")` was too short to answer :)

Comment: @VisioN yeah, was close - better luck next time :)

Comment: @BillyMoon That's why I so enjoy these *dynamic* JS-like tags :) It teach to think fast.